# why this program crash if i remove '0' from single_digits[*num - '0'])

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, char, c-strings

i found program how convert number to words but one thing i can't understand in string array single_digits[*num - '0']); why program is crashed when remove '0' in array index what is the use of '0' here

i am using GCC with code block windows
// C program to print a given number in words. The program handles numbers from 0 to 9999

```
#include <stdio.h> 
      #include <string.h> 
      #include <stdlib.h> 

// A function that prints given number in words */

    void convert_to_words(char *num) 
    { 
        int len = strlen(num); // Get number of digits in given number 

        /* Base cases */
        if (len == 0) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "empty string\n"); 
            return; 
        } 
        if (len > 4) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "Length more than 4 is not supported\n"); 
            return; 
        } 

// The first string is not used, it is to make 
//array indexing simple 
                 char *single_digits[] = { "zero", "one", "two", 
                                "three", "four","five", 
                                "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"}; 

// The first string is not used, it is to make 
            array indexing simple */
        char *two_digits[] = {"", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", 
                                "thirteen", "fourteen", 
                                "fifteen", "sixteen", 
                                "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"}; 

// The first two string are not used, they are to make 
 array indexing simple*/
            char *tens_multiple[] = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",             "fifty", 
                                "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"}; 

             char *tens_power[] = {"hundred", "thousand"}; 

// Used for debugging purpose only */
        printf("\n%s: ", num); 

// For single digit number */
          if (len == 1) { 
            printf("%s\n", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
            return; 
           } 

// Iterate while num is not '\0' */
          while (*num != '\0') { 

 // Code path for first 2 digits */
            if (len >= 3) { 
                if (*num -'0' != 0) { 
                    printf("%s ", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
                    printf("%s ", tens_power[len-3]); // here len can be 3 or 4 
                } 
                --len; 
            } 

  // Code path for last 2 digits */
            else { 
 // Need to explicitly handle 10-19. Sum of the two digits is 
 used as index of "two_digits" array of strings */
                if (*num == '1') { 
                    int sum = *num - '0' + *(num + 1)- '0'; 
                    printf("%s\n", two_digits[sum]); 
                    return; 
                } 

   // Need to explicitely handle 20 */
                else if (*num == '2' && *(num + 1) == '0') { 
                    printf("twenty\n"); 
                    return; 
                } 

 // Rest of the two digit numbers i.e., 21 to 99 */
                else { 
                    int i = *num - '0'; 
                    printf("%s ", i? tens_multiple[i]: ""); 
                    ++num; 
                    if (*num != '0') 
                        printf("%s ", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
                } 
            } 
            ++num; 
        } 
    } 
     /* Driver program to test above function */
    int main(void) 
    { 
        convert_to_words("9923"); 
        convert_to_words("523"); 
        convert_to_words("89"); 
        convert_to_words("8989"); 

        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::string` and pass by reference.  What happens if `num` is null or points to an invalid location?

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard (8.5.1.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
>   a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of
>   type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other
>   shall be a prvalue of **unscoped enumeration or integral type**...

In this code snippet

```
      if (len == 1) { 
        printf("%s\n", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
        ret
```

if this expression

```
single_digits[*num - '0']
```

to rewrite like

```
single_digits[*num]
```

then the sub-expression has the type `char` *that is an integer type) and its corresponding symbol is one of the following set `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`. `'9'`.

Internally these symbols as integers are stored for example in ASCII as numbers `48`, `49`, `50`, `51`, `52`, `53`, `54`, `55`, `56`, `57`.

The standard (5.3 Character sets) guarantees that

> 3. ... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each
>      character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits
>      shall be one greater than the value of the previous. T

If you will use these values as for example 50 that corresponds to the symbol `'2'` as an index of your arrays then the index will be outside the bounds of the arrays.

To get the correct index in the range of acceptable indices of your arrays you should use the expression

```
single_digits[*num - '0']
```

In this case you will have for example if `*num` is the symbol `'2'`

```
*num - '0' == '2' - '0' == 50 - 48 == 2
```

Comment: Better answer than mine, so let's stick with yours!